# Is there a way to pin a virtual PC VHD to the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

I have a virtual HD for Windows XP mode, and wanted to pin it to the task bar.

However, trying to pin the shortcut to the VHD file actually pins the "virtual machines" folder instead. Clicking on it opens the explorer window and I have to click on the VHD to actually open Windows XP.

It *does* know I'm trying to pin the file, and if I right-click the taskbar icon, has the file under "pinned," but the default action is what's under "Task" (which is to open the virtual machines folder in explorer).

Is there a way to pin the actual VHD to the taskbar, so it's just one click to restore the virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a [post on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5382578/pin-any-item-to-the-windows-7-taskbar) that provided the solution.

Basically, make a shortcut to the document or application, and change its target path to `explorer "<path-to-application>"` and move it to the taskbar.

Works like a charm.